# Including <div></div> in a library

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, header

I have a few "div" sections that are called by my Javascript function using document.getElementById('ID_NAME').style.display='block'.

My question, is there a way to include these "div's" in a .js, .css or another type of library sourced from my header?

If I copy and paste the div code directly into the head it works fine, however, when I try to include it in my .js or .css libraries it wont execute.

CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript>

function myFunction() {
var a = window.location.href;
var b = "http://www.myblog.com/";

if (a == b) {
setTimeout(function(){ 
document.getElementById('EXAMPLE1').style.display='block';}, 3000);}} 

window.onload = myFunction();

</script>

<div id="EXAMPLE1" class="offer_content">
<embed src="http://www.domain.com/" width="100%" 
height="100%">
</div>
```

I know there has to be a way to insert "div" code into a library.  I need some of my clients to "src" it into their own websites easily.

Much appreciated Stack community!

Jon

Comment: What do you mean by inserting a div? A solution to this problem is to create DOM elements and append it to body.

Comment: What do you mean here by "*library*"?

Comment: To clarify about the "div".  I'm looking to have a 3rd party website source my .js file, my .css file & also a file containing all of the <div>'s that my .js file calls.  EXAMPLE: <head> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MY-CSS.css"/>   <script type="text/javascript" src="MY-JS.js"></script> AND HERE IS WHERE I NEED A WAY TO SOURCE A FILE CONTAINING ALL OF MY <DIV> </DIV> CODE </head>.... It only works when I type in the <DIV> </DIV> code directly into the header.  I need a way for it to just source the same code like a .js file or .css file does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post that I finally worked this problem out.  While my Javascript library wouldn't support code with  *some code*  in it, I was able to convert everything with DOM.

OLD CODE::

```
<div id="EXAMPLE1" class="offer_content">
<embed src="http://www.domain.com/" width="100%" 
height="100%">
</div>
```

NEW CODE::

```
var embed = document.createElement('embed');
embed.setAttribute("src", "http://www.domain.com/");
embed.setAttribute("width", "100%"); 
embed.setAttribute("height", "100%");

var content = document.createElement('div');
content.id = 'EXAMPLE1';
content.className = 'offer_content';

content.appendChild(embed);

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

In another separate JS file, divs.js:

divs.js

```
function changeDiv(){
    document.getElementById('EXAMPLE1').style.display='block';
}
```

index.html

```
<script src="divs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {
var a = window.location.href;
var b = "http://www.myblog.com/";

if (a == b) {
    setTimeout(changeDiv, 3000);
}

window.onload = myFunction();

</script>

<div id="EXAMPLE1" class="offer_content">
<embed src="http://www.domain.com/" width="100%" 
height="100%">
</div>
```

Also, there seems to be syntax errors in your code. Try to run this file with a JS console (use something like "Firebug") for debugging purposes.

Comment: `setTimeout(changeDiv, 3000);`

Comment: Thanks for this, however, the issues is still occurring.  In an effort to try and simplify things (so everyone can move on to solving other frustrating problems).  All I need is a way to import the following code from a 3rd party source into my header (just like you do with .js files and .css files). CODE: <div id="NAME" class="CLASS NAME"><embed src"domainURL"></div>.  I only know how to import a .js file & .css file into my header, what do I use to import a file with the code above in it?